# Add alphabets to List Java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I want create a list with alphabets with each alphabets for 5 times. I tried a code and it worked,

```
public class AlphabetsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> alphabetList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            char chr='a';
            if (i==1)
                chr = 'b';
            if (i==2)
                chr = 'c';
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                alphabetList.add(chr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I would have to add multiple if conditions for more alphabets. Is there any better way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `char` loop as below,

```
List<Character> alphabetList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char chr = 'a'; chr <= 'c'; chr++){
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
            alphabetList.add(chr);
    }
}
```

You may also want to use, `Collections.nCopies` to avoid inner loop,

```
for(char chr = 'a'; chr <= 'c'; chr++){
    alphabetList.addAll(Collections.nCopies(5, chr));
}
```

Comment: Simply awesome. Second option option is like a champ. jus 2 lines of code.

Comment: One more help needed. What if I want 5 a, 10 b, 20 c. How can we manage this

Comment: You can create a Map with char and count and iterate over it with the above logic.

Comment: I didn't get you.